# Get cart data in opencart

Tags: php, opencart

How can I get cart information in open cart? I'm trying to get things like cart total in the  tag.

I've tried `$this->cart` (`Undefined property: Loader::$cart`), and `$registry->get('cart')`.

I'm editing `catalog/view/theme/default/template/common/header.tpl`

Comment: the `.tpl` is just a view file for the template engine.. Don't they use Twig ?

Answer (score 5):

You can't load the library files in .tpl files in Opencart 2.X, You have to do this in controller & assign that variable in template file. eg

```
// Write something like that in controller
$data['cartData'] = $this->cart->getProducts();
```

You can access the cart products in .tpl file in `$cartData` variable.

Comment: To display cart total in header in  a custom theme, what should be the way? I think editing controller is not ideal in this scenario. This is not related to what OP  asked. sry for that.

Comment: You can load the cart library & there is a method in cart library named getTotal, you can access it like $this->cart->getTotal();

Comment: Looks like I can not access $this in opencart 2.3.x. So I managed with OCMOD. However, still don't know it's the opencart way for this.

Comment: if you are on tpl level then yes you can't access it but you can do it like in your header controller $data['total'] = $this->cart->getTotal(); and print the $total variable in tpl file .. that's it.

Comment: You can go with vqmod or ocmod

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I did it (so i don't forget next time!)

in the file `catalog/controller/common/cart.php`

Line 138

You can store the `$data` variable in the $_SESSION:

`$_SESSION['cart_data'] = $data;`